# Difficulties while using SDL_CreateRGBSurface to create a new SDL_Surface

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm creating a basic console-based image processing tool in c++ and have thus far found creating functions that operate on RGB values super easy!

What I'd like to do now is create functions for blurring, sharpening and resizing the image. I know that in order to do this, I have to map the new pixels to a new image. I am having a bit of a problem using this in-built SDL function to create a new blank surface onto which I intend to map the new pixels:

```
SDL_Surface *SDL_CreateRGBSurface(Uint32 flags, int width, int height, int depth, Uint32 Rmask, Uint32 Gmask, Uint32 Bmask, Uint32 Amask);
```

The rest of my program uses `Uint8*` rather than `Uint32`, so I'm not sure how this will affect proceedings. Also, I'm not 100% sure about all of the parameters and what they do/are used for: ie flags and depth.

Can someone give me a bit of advice on how to use this function to properly create a new SDL_Surface?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a code example here that you can look at: http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.fcg/SDL_CreateRGBSurface

Specifically, the line you are looking for is:

```
surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0,width,height,32,0,0,0,0);
```

The flags are used for various things, but you should be able to set it to 0 fine. As for the depth, this refers to how many bits per pixel you are looking at. So in this case, 8 * 4 is 32 (including alpha).

I presume you already have the image loaded. If so, you can use this loaded image to get the bits per pixel instead:

```
surface->format->BitsPerPixel
```